# Like to vs like + ing

Tags: meaning, infinitives, ing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I like to do (be) something” vs “I like doing (being) something”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21498/i-like-to-do-be-something-vs-i-like-doing-being-something)

Hello,

Is there any difference of meaning between these sentences?

1. I like to get up early
2. I like getting up early

**UPDATE**

One teacher of mine suggested in his class that one of them (I can't remember which one)  meant that "I like it and I do it" while in the other case "I like it but I usually don't do it". t was justt to see if this difference really existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  `to get up` is a full infinitive used as a noun phrase, whereas `getting up` is a gerund (also a noun phrase).  Using the gerund is often considered more natural in this case, but it depends who you talk to.  Either way, the meaning is the same.

**Edit:** In this particular case, I still think the meaning is the same.  Someone would not say they appreciate getting up early without referring to some (implied) benefit ("I appreciate John getting up early"); they would only say "I like getting up early" if they actually do so themselves.

That said, your teacher is correct.  For example, `I like to ski` always means that the speaker has skiied and enjoys it.  `I like skiing` can mean the same thing, but can also mean `I like to watch skiing` or something similar.  It all depends on context.  If there's little context available, I would make it explicit which meaning you intend.

Comment: Please, see my update

Comment: @Juanillo Updated.

Comment: I agree with you. `I like to ski` means you enjoy the act of skiing. Whereas `I like skiing` could even mean you like the idea of skiing (or that you advocate skiing as a form of recreation, or many other things).