# "I love to [verb]" vs "I love [gerund]"

Tags: differences, gerunds, infinitives

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Catenatives followed by infinitives and gerunds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25075/catenatives-followed-by-infinitives-and-gerunds)
>   [“I like to do (be) something” vs “I like doing (being) something”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21498/i-like-to-do-be-something-vs-i-like-doing-being-something)

What is the difference between "I love to sing" and "I love singing"?

Comment: I love verbing!

Comment: you mean you love to verb?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The grammatical difference is that "I love to sing" uses an infinitive construction, whereas "I love singing" makes use of a gerund.

The difference in meaning is that "I love to sing" is referring to yourself singing, whereas "I love singing" could either refer to yourself singing or others singing.

Comment: so what's the difference between an infinitive construction and an gerund?

Comment: @Pacerier: Semantically, as I think drm65 implies even if he doesn't explicitly say it, the difference here is simply that the *gerund* denotes the *act of singing* - without implying anything about *who* performs that act. The *infinitive*, in this case at least, explicitly identifies the action as being performed by the speaker (and thus carries no ambiguity).