# "Would you mind to do something?"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is it correct to say "Would you mind to do something?". I've seen this usage in a few places, but it doesn't sound right to me. I would guess that it's proper to use "Would you mind doing something?" instead.

Yet there are other verbs we could substitute here that make it sound correct with "to". For example, "Would you like to do something?" and "Would you care to do something?"

Could someone explain why "mind to" doesn't sound correct in this context, while "like to" and "care to" sound exactly right?

Comment: I can’t answer the question of why this is, but I agree that it doesn’t scan right and has to be *mind **doing*** not *mind **to do***.

Comment: Maybe it's a function of the negative sense of the question?  If you substitute "object" (v.) (which I'd consider a close synonym to "mind", only maybe a bit stronger), the same situation applies: *Would you object to do something?* is definitely wrong, but *Would you object to doing something?* is fine.  Trying to think of other examples to see whether there's a clear distinction between positive and negative...

Comment: Related: [Why are the gerund and infinitive equally acceptable for some verbs, but not others](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64325/) ◊ [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive) (expressly mentions *mind*) ◊ [“I like to do (be) something” vs “I like doing (being) something”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21498/) ◊ [Catenatives followed by infinitives and gerunds](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25075/), and others.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, it's not correct.

The verb *mind* can take an [Equi](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) [Gerund](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/gerund.html) Complement clause:

- *Would you mind **doing something**?*

but **not** an Equi [Infinitive Complement](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/complements.pdf) clause:

- **Would you mind **to do something**?*

whence the asterisk on the second sentence, indicating that it's ungrammatical.

Verbs vary a lot in which complement clauses (if any) they can take; this is one part of the meaning of the verb. *Like* and *care* are both verbs that can take infinitive complement clauses; *mind* isn't. That's all, really.

Any good ESL dictionary should indicate which types of complement clause a verb can take; dictionaries for native speakers, on the other hand, usually don't mention that. One more reason not to look in dictionaries for grammatical information.