# Why is "doing" used here instead of "to do"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, gerunds

I have read this question: [“I like to do (be) something” vs “I like doing (being) something”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21498/i-like-to-do-be-something-vs-i-like-doing-being-something) and I get (although the answer could not be applied to my example) that using "to do" means *in general* I like to do it. While "doing", means I'm doing it *at the moment* or soon will be.

I found the following example in a grammar book:

> Exercise means doing something with the body.

Shouldn't it be "Exercising means doing..." or "Exercise means to do..." or maybe "To exercise means doing ..."

-I don't get why exercise is used as a noun here.

-I don't get why **doing** is used instead of **to do** and if they are interchangeable (without context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: [exercise is a noun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exercise)

> **Exercise** *noun* -
>
> 1. bodily or mental exertion, especially for the sake of training or
>    improvement of health: Walking is good exercise.
> 2. something done or performed as a means of practice or training:
>    exercises for the piano.

Secondly

> Exercise means doing something with the body.

*Doing* in this sense is a [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund). This means that *doing* is behaving as a verb within a noun phrase. So *doing something with the body* is effectively a noun that includes an action.

The sentence itself is acting as a definition for *exercise*, which is why the part after *means* is a noun.

To further clarify why using to *to do* is not natural, if you look at the [accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21498/i-like-to-do-be-something-vs-i-like-doing-being-something/21512#21512) to the question you link to, then you can read this:

> The infinitival is more associated with change, the gerund-participle with actuality.

Since your sentence is a definition, it is actuality, therefore we use the gerund *doing* not the infinitive *to do*.

Comment: I think *doing* might be a [gerund](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000335.htm)

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: ok, but why use "doing" here and not "to do" instead?

Comment: @repecmps Because the infinitive of the verb (i.e. *to do*) doesn't fit into the noun phrase. You need to use a gerund for that.

Comment: @repecmps: It's a parallel: the sentence says "noun means noun". "Doing" can be a noun, but 'to do' is a verb.

Comment: @simchona: this satisfies me as an answer. (oh, and matt also said the same thing in comment)