# "How easy is it to *verb*..." vs. "How easy is *verb*..."

Tags: differences, verbs, gerund-vs-infinitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one know when to use a gerund or a infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-does-one-know-when-to-use-a-gerund-or-a-infinitive)

What is the difference in connotation between

> How easy is it to "some *verb* here"

and

> How easy is "some *verb* here"

What is the significance of using "it" in the first example?

Comment: General reference. Too basic.

Comment: Related: [When to use a gerund or an infinitive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-does-one-know-when-to-use-a-gerund-or-a-infinitive) and [I like to do something or I like doing something](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21498/i-like-to-do-be-something-vs-i-like-doing-being-something)

Comment: @KitFox apt! was helpful!

Answer (score 4):

The 'some verb' bit needs a different form, e.g.

> How easy is it *to* program?

but

> How easy is programming?

Both can be used in a general sense, in this case either form might be asked by someone considering a new career, but the first could also be used about a specific task.

Comment: yes David, the syntax I typed is a bit misleading. feel free to edit it.

Comment: "specificity" - noted in the case when nothing else is mentioned. "How easy is to drive a car" or "How easy is driving a car"? - what if something else is mentioned that is connected to the verb driving or any other verb in its place? or even for that matter drop the "a car" part

Comment: "How easy is it to drive a car" and "How easy is driving a car" contain their own specificity, and are equivalent. "How easy is it to drive" and "How easy is driving" are again equivalent in the general case (where "it" is abstract), but the former could also be used in a specific case (where "it" is a particular car).

Comment: so it always points to something; even if its invisible in the sentence. OK.

Answer (score 0):

"How easy is *to do something*" is not a correctly formed English sentence. You can say:

- "how easy is it *to play the guitar*", or
- "how easy is *playing the guitar*"

but not "how easy is to play the guitar".