# Should I use 'to'?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I have two verbs in a sentence. I know I have to use 'to' before each verb. But in this case it sounds a little bit strange to me.

Should I use *to* there?

> Test that this method returns right data and to works correctly.

Comment: What do you want to say? Improve your question, because as it is, it's rather unclear, in my opinion.

Comment: No, "and (test that it) works correctly".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

Your sentence is grammatically incorrect as given.  Without *to* and with an extra *the*, it is correct:

> Test that this method returns the right data and works correctly.

(*The* is needed with *right data* since *right* implies that there is only one acceptable set of data.)

I’m not sure why you would expect that *to* to be there.

Comment: But, as I know I have to use 'to' before each verb. Right?

Comment: I guess he's confused with the "infinite" to + verb... @Misho: only when it's infinite or when the previous statement requires it (and it usually requires an infinite tense so...), but not always.

Comment: There are some verbs, such as *refuse,* that take infinitives like "to work" after them; for example: "I refuse to work on Sundays." There are some verbs that don't, such as *test.* As far as I know, there is no rule; you just have to memorize or look up which verbs are which.

Comment: Related to what @Peter says: [Verbs followed by...](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/gerund-or-infinitive-when-to-use-which/330#330)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the excellent answers already given, I wanted to make a pitch for using parallel structure. It has helped me figure out some otherwise tricky sentence constructions.  In general, you want your verbs to match when they are associated using an *and* or an *or*.  In your sentence:

> Test that this method returns right data and to works correctly.

the verbs that you want to match are "returns" and "works", because they are joined by the *and*.  This would give you two alternatives:

> Test that this method returns right data and works correctly.

OR

> Test that this method to return right data and to work correctly.

Now since "returns" and "works" goes with "this method", the infinitive doesn't work here, so we're left with:

> Test that this method returns right data and works correctly.

(@PLL is right about adding the "the" as well.)

As an example of how you might structure the sentence to use parallel infinitives, consider:

> Run a test to see if this method returns the correct data and to check for errors.

In this construction, "to see" and "to check" are coordinated with the *and*, so they should match.  Matching with infinitives is less strict, though, because it is okay to drop the extra *to*:

> Run a test to see if this method returns the correct data and check for errors.

Although personally, I think it is less clear this way.

This [crib sheet](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/1/) has some other examples of parallelism, including other parts of speech.

Answer (score 1):

Without really knowing what your example sentence is supposed to mean... I can tell you that "to works" is incorrect. It's either "to work" or "works".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the 'to' necessarily, but the sentence has errors beyond the 'to'.

Try this:

> Run a test to see if this method
>   returns the correct data and that it
>   works correctly.