# Repeating "to" in a list of verbs connected by "and"

Tags: prepositions, punctuation, commas, writing, parallelism

> "This group’s main duties are to carry out information systems audits in Colombian banks and to make research and develop new regulations on information technologies and systems in the banking sector."

Should I put a "***to***" behind "***develop***"? Or are any other commas needed?

Comment: I think its correct as it is.It all makes right sense.

Comment: I believe you don't need the word "make" there.

Comment: We are saying "make research on information technologies...". Shouldn't "make" be there?

Comment: *Make* in the example refers to *new regulations*: you will be making, researching and developing the regulations. It makes sense, but I would guess that's not what you meant (certainly not in that order).

Comment: Related: [“To do this or do that” or “To do this or *to* do that”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51851/to-do-this-or-do-that-or-to-do-this-or-to-do-that)

Comment: related: [Should I use "to"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26596/should-i-use-to)

Comment: Related: [Gerund or infinitive: when to use which](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/gerund-or-infinitive-when-to-use-which)

Comment: One **does** research. Not _make_.

Comment: @JohnLawler But one doesn't say *do research sth.* -that's a bit awkward. It's either just *research sth.* or, perhaps, *undertake research*.

Comment: That's on one reading, and not the most likely one. The prepositional phrases don't have to be governed by _do research_; the research can be of any sort, including precisely what's relevant. Commas don't decide meanings; they simply help or hinder our interpretations, which is what meaning **really** is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would better be:

> ... in Colombian banks, to ***undertake*** research and ***to*** develop new regulations ...

Note that in your version, *and* is used twice. Unless you meant to say 'research and development' as a single task, you will have to use a comma as above.

As for the ***to***, yes, it is needed, again unless you meant to say 'research and development' as a single task.

---

[Edit-1]
On the other hand, if you had meant 'research and development' as a single task:

> in Colombian banks and to ***undertake*** research and ***development of*** new regulations ...

Comment: Yes, research and development as a single task was what I meant.

Comment: Oh well, then it's going to be quite different.

Comment: I think 'R & D' should be *on* a subject. Normally just pedantic,but here *of* would naturally refer only to development. (which has already caused some confusion).

Comment: @TimLymington I agree with you. I had indeed thought of this. However, even *R&D on* doesn't fit at all: it is *on* for R and *of* for D :( if you check carefully! We generally skirt the issue by placing the R&D *after* than before.

Answer (score 0):

How about "The group's main tasks are (i) to carry out information audits in Colombian banks and (ii) to undertake research and development concerning new regulations on information technologies and systems in the banking sector"?  It's unwieldy, but it's grammatical and (if read carefully) unambiguous.
I am guessing to a certain extent what your intentions are, as the original can be read several ways; that is the penalty for using *and* too much.

Also, I don't personally like the phrase *information technologies*.  *Information technology* is an idiom for computers and related machines; *information technologies* would include the fax, the photocopier, and paper and pencil.  But this isn't a universal view: if your readers will understand the phrase, by all means include it.

Comment: My readers are a bunch of university professors and information security experts. "IT" would mean the same to them all.