# Which is (more) correct?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

> Why don't you try [to speak OR speaking] to him in Spanish? ...

Which variant is more correct and why?

Comment: The two variants have different shades of meaning. See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117345/how-to-remember-the-difference-between-can-you-try-to-open-and-can-you-try-o?rq=1)

Comment: @KillingTime When you edit, could you attend to the titles as well, please?