# try + ing vs. try to + infinitive

Tags: grammar, verbs, gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

Which sentence is correct:

> Why don't you **try to give up** candy if you want to lose some weight?
>
> Why don't you **try giving up** candy if you want to lose some weight?

Comment: Both are correct, I find the second more natural.

Comment: @tchrist That generic question doesn't really explain the difference in meaning in this particular sentence.

Comment: @Gilles Perhaps one of the [18 questions linked to it](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/384?lq=1) would be better. The matter of choosing an *-ing* form of a verb versus choosing its *to*-infinitive is hardly new here.

Comment: @tchrist Ah, after a bit of digging I found http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61552/try-to-save-or-try-saving — that one is indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 8):

Both sentences are correct. They have a different meaning.

“Try to” implies that the action that is attempted may or may not succeed. Try to give up candy; maybe you will succeed in refraining from eating candy, or maybe you will succumb to the temptation and eat candy anyway.

“Try + -ing” indicates that the action may or may not have the desired result. Try giving up candy; if you do give up candy, maybe you will lose weight, or maybe you will not.