# How did 'to purport' evolve to connote negativity?

Tags: etymology

I already understand and so ask NOT about the definition, below which I want to burrow. I heed the Etymological Fallacy. Please beware that I replicate the noun(al) etymology from Etymonline, and not the verbal because the verbal just refers you back to the noun(al).

> [OED Etymology for **purport {verb} :**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/154969?rskey=emNi8u&result=2) < Anglo-Norman and Middle French *purporter*
>   (of a text) to have as its import, to signify, to mean, to state or show (a fact) (all first half of the 14th cent. or earlier in Anglo-Norman ;
>    end of the 13th cent. or earlier in Anglo-Norman in sense ‘(of a word) to mean, signify’;
>   late 12th cent. in Old French as *porporter* in sense ‘to involve (as an obligation)’)
>   < post-classical Latin *proportare* to carry or bear forth (8th cent. in past participle *proportatus* ), to stretch, extend (from 12th cent. in British sources; from 13th cent. in continental sources; also as porportare ), to have as its import (from c1200 in British sources; also as *porportare* )
>   < classical Latin  [PRO- (prefix)<sup>1</sup>](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/151666) + *portāre* [PORT v.<sup>2</sup>](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/148098), perhaps as a remodelling of classical Latin *praeportāre* to carry in front, in post-classical Latin also to stretch, extend (in an undated source in Du Cange)
>   < *prae-* PRE- (prefix) + *portāre* . Compare proport v.
>
> [Etymonline for **purport {noun}** :](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=purport&searchmode=none) early 15c., from Anglo-French *purport* (late 13c.), Old French *porport* "contents, tenor," back-formation from *purporter* "to contain, convey, carry," from *pur-* (from Latin *pro-* "forth;" see [pur-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pur-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + Old French *porter* "to carry," from Latin *portare* "to carry" (see [port](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=port&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.1)).

Comment: If all you can confidently assert is that something is purported, then you can't say it's true, and you have your suspicions. [This is a Gricean interpretation](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/61558/15299) -- it follows from the Maxim of Quantity: Say as much as you know that is true. If that's all you know that's true, it's a dubious proposition. And it doesn't connote "negativity" -- it's not a negative -- rather, it connotes doubt.

Comment: The preposition that follows the word is everything. In 1949, purportedly, as "allegedly", followed "purport to", as "claim to". see https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purport+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cpurport%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpurport%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpurport%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpurport%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpurport%20was%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpurport%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpurport%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpurport%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpurport%20or%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpurport%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpurport%20are%3B%2Cc0