# What's the difference between say "I started working" vs "I started to work"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, tenses

Simple question

What's the difference between someone say

```
"I started working on something..."
```

And

```
"I started to work on something..."
```

Comment: _Start_, like _try_, is an aspectual verb referring to the circumstances around some action, state, or event. As such, it has its own grammar and usage, like all auxiliaries and near-auxiliaries. In particular, _start_ with an infinitive complement is often subject to a [Gricean implicature of non-completion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61558/15299), whereas _start_ with a gerund isn't. _I started to open it, but I found it wouldn't budge_ is OK, but not with _I started opening it_, which implies that some opening occurred.

Comment: John Lawler's answer clearly distinguishes this particular example from the more general claimed duplicate. Note that OP's 'say' licenses the broadened reply.

Comment: They have different implications is right. This concerns particularly verbs of starting (beginning) and finishing (stopping).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the main difference is the structure of the verb. The first sentence utilizes a present participle while the second sentence uses an infinitive. (*To*+verb=infinitive.)

PS: For those that might argrue that "working" in this context is a gerund, I would suggest to look at 5.113 in the 17th edition of the CMS. There it says as follows: "A particple...can be modified **only** by an adverb. A gerund...can be modified **only** by an adjective." You'll see that "working" in this context can only be modified by an adverb. (E.g. I started working [tirelessly, frequently, etc.])

Answer (score -1):

No difference in meaning period both correct.