# The verb 'TRY': Transitive or Intransitive

Tags: infinitives

Consider these sentences, please:

Try ***to complete the examination***

He tried ***to climb a cliff.***

Are the to-infinitives the objects of the verb ***try*** Or are they *infinitives of purpose*?

Comment: The "object of the verb" sense would apply in contexts such as *He **tried the door**, but it was locked*, which is *semantically* the same as *He tried **to open** the door*, even though the syntax is different.

Comment: Yes, clauses, like infinitive clauses, gerund clauses, _that_-clauses, and _wh_-clauses, can be direct objects of certain verbs. Each verb is different. _Try_ can take a noun or pronoun object (_He never tried that before_), a gerund object (_He tried waterskiing and didn't like it_), or an infinitive object, as you point out. There is [a minor usage difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61558/15299) between the gerund and infinitive complements of _try_, though.

Comment: Although, come to think of it, there is no real semantic difference between the complement of _try_, which describes what the attempt is sposta accomplish, and a real infinitive of purpose. _Try_ ***means*** 'purpose'.

Comment: @JohnLawler: With my "bare" example *He tried the door* (no ***to open*** or ***opening***) there could in principle be a genuine semantic difference. Usually,  trying a door would imply attempting to open it *just a little bit* (the default "purpose" being to establish whether or not it's actually ***locked***). But it seems like there's a significant difference in how the verb works between *He tried the door, but it was locked* and, say, *He tried the door, **but it was too small for him to get through***.

Comment: That's the "minor usage difference" I noted above; follow that link for more details.

Comment: Then there's 'try someone's patience'. This isn't usually an 'attempt', but I can see it as a broadened usage.

Comment: I think that's the same _try_ as _try the bacon_, i.e, heat until fat runs out. Though it could also be the _try_ of 'try your luck'.

Comment: **to complete the examination** and  **to climb a cliff** can both be replaced by “it”.== **to complete the examination** and  **to climb a cliff** can both be the subject of a verb. == **to complete the examination** and  **to climb a cliff** are infinitive clauses (they act as nouns.) ==**To try** is a transitive verb in the context you give. == In each example, to try has an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments John Lawler wrote:

> Yes, clauses, like infinitive clauses, gerund clauses, *that*-clauses, and *wh*-clauses, can be direct objects of certain verbs. Each verb is different. *Try* can take a noun or pronoun object (*He never tried that before*), a gerund object (*He tried waterskiing and didn't like it*), or an infinitive object, as you point out. There is [a minor usage difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61558/15299) between the gerund and infinitive complements of *try*, though.

And also:

> Although, come to think of it, there is no real semantic difference between the complement of *try*, which describes what the attempt is supposed to accomplish, and a real infinitive of purpose. *Try* ***means*** 'purpose'.