# What effect is achieved when using the gerundive form versus the infinitive form in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, gerunds, infinitives

Gerundive: Try getting some rest.

Infinitive: Try to get some rest.

My textbook says that the former means "Attempt to get some rest" while the latter means to "try getting some rest as a possible solution to the problem".

They feel very familiar and I find them indistinguishable if I were to see them in a text.

Thus, I have the following questions:

1. Can they be used interchangeably, or is one more grammatically correct than the other?
2. If so, why does being gerundive or infinitive impart a different meaning to the two phrases?
3. What grammatical functions do gerunds and infinitives play other than changing the function of a verb to a noun, adjective, or adverb?

Comment: They are both correct but have different meanings. There is no "functional change", as you put it, so I don't understand your question 3.

Comment: Note that the gerund-participial is **not** functioning as or like a noun -- that is simply nonsense. "Try" is a catenative verb and the gerund-participial clause "getting some rest" is its catenative complement. "Noun" has no relevance here.

Comment: The default pragmatic sense of both is _You need to rest. In spite of all the pressures you're experiencing._ The first _could_ be a suggestion of a suitable strategem (You've tried A, B, drinking lots of coffee ... now try this.) Perhaps in 10% of cases.

Comment: There's a pragmatic difference between the constructions. _Try to `V`_ has [a Gricean implicature attached](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61558/15299). _Try `V`-ing_ doesn't.

Comment: No: the default pragmatic sense of both is not "You need to rest". It is for "try" + infinitival, but there's no such implicature with "try" + gerund-participial. It may simply be suggesting an alternative to some other 'remedy' for some ailment, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *Try* [*getting some rest*].
>
> [2] *Try* [*to get some rest*].

There is a difference in meaning.

[1] means "test the effectiveness of", while [2] means "endeavour".

Both clauses are functioning as complement of "try".

Answer (score 1):

I would say it was the other way round!

The *infinitive* (the latter) means 'Attempt to do it'. You might advise someone recovering from an illness to try to get some rest because it would help them.

The gerund[ive] functions like a noun. As your textbook says, 'getting some rest' is suggested as a possible solution to a problem (such as not being able to think clearly).

Neither is 'more correct' than the other, but there is this slight difference in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It's all a matter of "point of view" from the speaker.

"getting" is thematic. "-ing" is about an activity already experienced (in the past). "-ing" is looking backwards, so to speak ;)

"to get" is rhematic. "to" is about a destination, about something to be experienced (in the future). "to" is looking forward ;)

Comment: In _Try getting some rest_, "try" means  'test the effectiveness of', while in _Try to get some rest_, it means "endeavour".