# "Attempts to acquaint" vs. "attempts at acquainting"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, infinitives, gerunds

> The research study is an eye-opener and **attempts to
>   acquaint/attempts at acquainting** us with the problems of poor
>   nations.

For me, *attempts to acquaint* sounds more apt. But I am not sure about the latter one. Also, in my answer sheet, the latter one is given as the right answer. But I have heard phrases like *attempt to murder.*  Could anyone explain the correct usage?

Comment: "explain the correct usage". I was schooled in the classically liberating thought that there isn't any circumstance where we should presume "correct use" of English or "correct English". Rather we should attempt "appropriate, proper or acceptable" use of English compatible with the normal regional patterns of English usage.

Comment: @Blessed Geek. _He sedded that they all time wonderful a had were_ isn’t correct in any variety of the language. :)

Comment: Sudhir may be able to find the answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive

Comment: @Barrie England: Great ! I admire you linguistic competency.

Comment: But what will be correct answer as 'attempt' is followed by both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is not actually about whether you should use *acquaint* or *acquainting*. That is a side-effect of the preposition/particle which follows *attempts*.

*Attempts* **can** be followed by *at* (and a gerund) if *attempts* is a noun. Note that it **can** also use *to* and the infinitive form of the verb.

> I made several attempts at doing that.

If *attempts* is a verb, it must be followed by *to* and an infinitive.

> It attempts to do that.

The question is testing how the parts of the sentence are parsed. Here, *attempts* is a verb and must be followed by *to* and an infinitive.

If the sentence is lengthened, then *attempts* can be made into a noun, but an additional comma helps:

> The research study is an eye-opener, and attempts at acquainting us with the problems of poor nations are ultimately successful.

Answer (score 1):

*Attempts to acquaint* is grammatical and *attempts at acquainting* isn’t. If *attempts* is to be followed by the *-ing* form at all, it must be without *at*.

In some cases where both are possible, the *to-* infinitive describes a possible action, while an *-ing* clause describes the actual performance of the action. In this case, the verb *attempts* means that the act of acquainting us with the problems of poor nations has not been completed, or even initiated, leaving the  *to-* infinitive as the only sensible choice.

Comment: @Sudhir, [whichever questions you are using](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="The+research+study+is+an+eye-opener+and+attempts"+"us+with+the+problems+of+poor+nations."), change supplier! It seems that the questions you are given to answer are unclear or ambiguous and the answers provided at least unexplained if not actually wrong.

Comment: @Andrew Leach:Here supplier means?

Comment: The supplier is the person you get the questions from. I'm inclined to agree with @AndrewLeach here.

Answer (score 0):

**Attempt** can be both a verb and a noun. When used as a verb, it is more commonly followed by "to" and the infinitive. So

> The research study attempts to acquaint us ... .

is the more expected pattern than

> The research study attempts at acquainting us ... .

If the sentence were to be rewritten slightly to use **attempt** as a plural noun, then both continuations seem roughly equally acceptable:

> The research study makes attempts to acquaint us with the problems of
>    poor nations.
>
> The research study makes attempts at acquainting us with
>    the problems of poor nations.