# Must I use "infinitive" or "gerund" form in the following examples?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

"**To know** her and **to live** with her are two distinctly different situations". or
"**Knowing** her and **living** with her are two distinctly different situations".

Comment: What exactly is your problem with those? Both  are grammatical and idiomatic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Being" or "to be"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239964/being-or-to-be). Actually, [gerund versus infinitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/522941/gerund-versus-infinitive) is a closer match, with to-infinitive and ing-form in sentence-initial position, but was closed as a duplicate of this.

Comment: @John Lawler stated as part of a comment: 'There are general, very rough, guidelines for complement usage: gerunds correspond to events, while infinitives correspond to situation types. That-clauses correspond to propositions.'

Comment: @Robusto I'd like to know if both are correct or if there is any rule which explains when I should use one way or the other one.

Comment: Both are fine. I'd use the first one for a rhetorically stronger or more formal statement. The second is more conversational.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've just read the post you recommended, but even though it's related to 'gerund' and 'infinitive', I don't think it's the same case of which I'm asking. But I like your second comment could you explain it a little bit more? or, maybe, could you give some example sentences?

Comment: Awesome!! thanks a lot @Robusto

Comment: [John Lawler's answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328588/when-to-use-a-gerund-or-an-infinitive-after-is/328595#328595) should help. He addresses to-infinitive-, ing-form- and that-clauses in both sentence-initial and the more usual positions.