# Continue working vs continue to work

Tags: present-perfect, past-vs-present

I found this explanation: http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic38633.html

but what about present?

I continue to work or I continue working? Are they the same?

Answer (score 3):

They're practically the same, I'd use `working` to stress that you're presently actively doing it:

> I will continue working on this until lunch.
>
> I will continue to work for them until I can afford to move.

But this is a personal preference, and nobody can fault you for just following your ear here.

Comment: I don't really see how a non-native speaker can "follow their ear" (unless you mean "copy what you hear native speakers say"). The infinitive [has always been more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=continued+working+on%2Ccontinued+to+work+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontinued%20working%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinued%20to%20work%20on%3B%2Cc0), but that may eventually change. If there are any contexts where native speakers would distinguish on *semantic* grounds (incl. *emphasis*), I can't think of one offhand.

Comment: A non-native speaker's ear is inexperienced, but they can still follow their ear. If their ear is influenced by their native language, this creates something similar to an accent in speech--it's distinctive but not wrong.

Comment: There's a slow but inexorable rise in the use of gerund/continuous for this and many similar contexts in English. I've no idea how many other languages have meaningfully comparable constructions, but it seems unlikely there would be any *consistent* correlation for such usages across languages. I think rather than follow his ear, the learner should follow [the excellent advice](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/330/2637) given to the original question.