# Is this tutorial using "to [verb]-ing" the right way? When should I just use "to [verb]"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, gerund-vs-infinitive, adverbials, predicate-frames, nonfinite-verbs

That [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-perform-exploratory-data-analysis-with-seaborn-97e3413e841d) says

> Exploratory Data Analysis (EDA) is an approach **to analyzing** datasets **to summarize** their main characteristics. It is used to understand data, get some context regarding it, understand the variables and the relationships between them, and formulate hypotheses that could be useful when building predictive models.

[image]

Both "to doing" and "to do" are used in this sentence, "an approach to analyzing datasets to summarize their main characteristics".

By "to doing" and "to do", I mean "to analyzing" and "to summarize" respectively.

I know "doing (in this case, analyzing data sets)" is a gerund that could be the subject or object of sentences, but when should I use "to doing"? This kind of usage confuses me, so I searched these keywords.

This [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/259503/362815) discussed "to doing" but didn't give a doable guide when to use which. I guess that's why the asker didn't mark any of the answer as accepted.

Leave a general talking alone, consider this particular case, is that tutorial use "to doing" the right way? When should I use "to doing"?

**Note:** I am asking what situation should I use "to doing" rather than what is gerund.

Comment: "To doing" what?  What words are you talking about?

Comment: When you write "to doing" and "to do" do you mean "to analyzing" and "to summarize"?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, I've updated.

Comment: To be clear, you are not asking about the literal text "to doing" versus "to do." I spent several minutes looking at the quotation in the question without finding that text, and being quite confused. (I edited the title of your question to make it more obvious to anyone else.) In short, what you're really asking is when to use the infinitive and when to use the present participle. (It's not a gerund in this case; *to summarize* is not being used as a noun.)

Comment: @JasonBassford the quotation is right at the first paragraph of the link, I uploaded the screenshot just now.

Comment: @yaojp You missed my point. By actually writing the text "to doing" and "to do" (in quotes), you set the expectation that that *exact* text appears. But it doesn't. Nowhere in that quotation (either in your transcription or the screenshot you just provided) does "to doing" or "to do" appear. (I spent a a considerable amount of time looking for it, then finally conducted a *find* in my browser.) That fact that it doesn't, literally, appear is what was causing confusion. And the last part of my first comment still applies: *to analyzing* is not a gerund, it's a (present participle) verb.

Comment: As Professor Lawler observes in one of the linked-to rededuplicative questions: ***“Every English verb is has its own rules for what kinds of Object Complement clauses it permits, requires, or forbids.”*** If you are a speaker of another language trying to learn English, then we invite you to visitour sister site for  [ell.se], which may be better suited to help you.

Comment: @tchrist "is has" ?