# “dedicated to helping people ” or “dedicated to help people”

Tags: grammar, infinitives, gerunds

I have this sentence:

> I'm a volunteer in an organization that is dedicated to **helping** people find answers about life in the Bible.

or it should be

> I'm a volunteer in an organization that is dedicated to **help** people find answers about life in the Bible.

Which is correct?

Comment: The first version has a more natural "sound" to it (although both are wordy as written descriptions).

Comment: First one is definitely more idiomatic, even though second is acceptable to some degree.

Comment: I don't even think the second one is considered correct grammatically because [the tense](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/verb-tenses-adding-ed-and-ing) is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive)

Comment: @AlexW -- Come again?

Answer (score 2):

You must use the gerund (*-ing* form) in this case.

*Dedicate* and its derivatives take as complement a preposition phrase headed by *to* ...

> He dedicated his life **to music**.
>   This work is dedicated **to my wife**.
>   Harold's dedication **to his job** precluded romantic relationships.

The *to* in *to help people* lost its prepositional sense about 700 years ago; it is now regarded as an *infinitive marker*. And the *help* in *to help people* cannot be understood as a noun; the noun *help* does not take an object.

The only verbform which can both act as the nominal object of a preposition **and** itself take an object is the *-ing* form, which is called a *gerund* when it plays the role of a noun.