# Watch the sun go down

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitive

In the sentence:

> I'd like to watch the sun go down

why there is no "to"?

Why not:

> I'd like to watch the sun to go down

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/329/26083) (see **Verbs Followed by Either the Simple Form or the Gerund (no “to”)**).

Comment: See  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292089/explanation-of-grammatical-structure-is-needed  -  verb + noun + to-infinitive and verb + noun + bare infinitive

Answer (score 7):

Because it's an exception. An infinitive loses its *to* when it follows certain verbs like *let*, *hear*, *feel*, *watch* and some others.

Comment: Is there a name for this class of verbs?

Comment: @user1359 Sometimes they are called "verbs of perception". At least verbs like see, hear, watch, feel, smell, notice and some others.

Check out this link: http://www.grammaring.com/see-watch-hear-listen-feel-smell-notice-observe-object-bare-infinitive