# "Seeing someone slowly lose interest in you is one of the worst things."?

Tags: questions

I'm new here and the sentence "Seeing someone slowly lose interest in you is one of the worst things." Same with "Watching someone die.." Why are the verbs "lose" and "die" in their base form? Also are "seeing" and "watching" gerund or progressive?

Comment: An excellent question, Emma, and one that that has answer that you may obtain by clicking "Tags" in the menu below the EL&U title and searching for "bare infinitive."  Come back and ask if you're still confused.   As for your second question, the sentence has the form Subject-Copulative Verb-Complement.  The Verb = *is*; the Complement = *one* [of the worst].  When you figure out the subject, you'll know the type of verb form for *seeing*.  I don't find "watching" in your sentence.

Comment: You can search a lot of answers here. [*For example*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278929/watch-the-sun-go-down)

Comment: @deadrat and Rathony, thank you very much! You helped a kid who is still learning the English language. Bless you and may you share more of your knowledge to our fellow men and women!

Comment: @Rathony thank you very much! You helped a kid who is still learning the English language. Bless you and may you share more of your knowledge to our fellow men and women! –