# Explanation of Grammatical structure is needed

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntactic-analysis

> The crowd **saw** him **clap** his hand to his mouth.
>
> ---

This is a sentence from *Harry Potter I*. I don't understand how *"clap"* is used right after *"saw"*. Shouldn't there be a *"to"* in between? i.e. *"saw him to clap"* seems appropriate.

Comment: Compare: I heard her sing that song.  I felt it touch the back of my neck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two verb constructions of the type verb + object + infinitive.

The normal construction is verb + object + to-infinitive as in

- I want you to help me.

A small group of verbs use only bare infinitive:

1 All verbs of perception as eg to see, hear, feel etc.

- I heard the girls laugh ("laughing" is also possible).

2 Verbs of cause and allowance:

- to make s (someone) do sth, to have s do sth, older: to bid s do sth - to let s do sth
- You make me laugh. Let the children come to me.

I searched the Internet for information about these two verb constructions. What I found is miserable.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I know why the search was miserable?

Comment: The presentation of this grammar point is botchwork.

Answer (score 2):

A verb of perception can take an object + bare infinitive.

> I saw two men cut down a tree.

A bare infinitive means a complete action here.