# To + verb, bare verb or verb + ing in noun phrases

Tags: verbs, infinitives, ing

I've asked this around and I'm RACKING MY BRAIN trying to figure it out.

Which one is the correct verb form in the following sentence?

> The craziest thing I've ever done is **go / to go / going** scubadiving in Belize

Some people say that both the *to + verb* and the *ing* forms are correct, because you need a noun there and the bare form is a verb; other people say **only** the *to + verb* is the correct one here, because the ing form only applies when you reverse the sentence (*going scubadiving is yadda yadda*) and not when you place the subject in the end.

I know many people would use the bare infinitive to be quicker while speaking, but that just sounds wrong to my ears as it's a verb!

Can you please tell me, once and for all, which is the correct verb form?

Comment: I think this would be better asked on our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: Mostly because they're better at explaining this kind of stuff in an accessible way. We have people here too, and you'll get an answer, but you'll get more and faster answers there. That's all. This site tends to focus on the more abstract and theoretical (i.e. *nerdier*) aspects of English. But no matter, if you want to keep it here, that's fine by me, I won't get in your way.

Comment: @DanBron: It's now been [cross-posted](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85117/to-verb-bare-verb-or-verb-ing-in-noun-phrases).

Comment: Loosely related: [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/329/26083)

Comment: @LaviniaRaspelli It takes time for SE to delete an account. So, in the meantime, however you are viewing the site, *close that view*.

Comment: Tell me what to do: I log out but I still see the notifications. Can you guys be clear for once and tell me STEP BY STEP what to click on?

Comment: If you still want to delete your account, you can follow the instructions [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Answer (score -2):

The answer here is "go". Consider the sentence...

> The craziest thing I've ever done is ...

**Progressive Usage**

The conjugation, "going" is considered progressive/continuous. In your sentence, you are not *in the process of* scuba-diving in Belize. Or giving a specific description of *what it's like scuba-diving in Belize.* So you want to cross this one off and not use it.

**Infinitive Redundancy**

Now... We consider using "to go". Hmm... Well isn't that just the infinitive of "go"? Yes, so in this case remove the redundant "to" What are we left with now? *Go*.

**Infinitive Usage**

We will use *go* here. We are not interested in describing what scuba-diving in Belize was like (within this exact sentence). We are only saying that... It *happened*.

Comment: @LaviniaRaspelli take a gander at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/verb-tenses-adding-ed-and-ing

Comment: @LaviniaRaspelli you are confusing infinitive verbs with indefinite pronouns... http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/nounphrase.htm

Comment: The reasoning for avoiding the to-infinitive is unsound. "[The only] solution is to lower the standards" is idiomatic (98 200 Google hits for the 6-word string), whereas "[The only] solution is lower the standards" is not (1 Google hit for the 5-word string). With OP's example, there are 28 500 Google hits for "ever done is go" (showing that it is acceptable, I'd say) but 391 000 Google hits for "ever done is to go" (showing that this is the preferred option).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth go and say "ever done is to go" out loud to yourself. There is something not right about the way it sounds. Let me know what you think when you say it aloud.

Comment: The reason I commented was because I was at least as happy with 'The craziest thing I've ever done is to go scuba diving in Belize' than with The craziest thing I've ever done is go scuba diving in Belize'. And the Google results would seem to go further in showing the preferred variant. // Many contributors to ELU could say 'I am a native English speaker with a lot of language experience'. But most of us have come to understand that this is not usually adequate authority.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in either case you're using the infinitive. I think this enters into the territory of verbal linguistics, one of the answers doesn't work well when spoken and that is "to go".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth http://ehlt.flinders.edu.au/education/DLiT/2008/multipleintel/lingfr.html

Comment: '... one of the answers doesn't work well when spoken and that is "to go" .' In your humble opinion. With which I disagree.

Comment: "My favorite exercise is swimming." is fine.  "My favorite exercise is to swim." is awkward.  "My favorite exercise is swim." is just plain wrong.

Comment: @Scott When you say "swim" it is proper to say "going swimming" when you say "going" it should be "go scubadiving". It's verbal-linguistics... Inexpressible nuances of the language. The solution here would be to omit "go" altogether.

Comment: @Scott But there isn't a simple general rule here. "solution is lowering the standards" shows only 1 relevant Google hit, "solution is lower the standards" also 1, but  "solution is to lower the standards" 98 000.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I know you keep going back to that... But how many of those things will actually be verbalized? I think the verbalization must get factored into constructing the sentence properly.

Comment: You are giving your opinion about what sounds better. This doesn't tally with my opinion, or, it seems, with the majority of those choosing between various variants as shown in a Google search.  As tchrist has said, 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree with you that (in the comments) I am giving only an opinion, but in the answer above I don't say anything about the verbal correctness. That is why we are here in the comments having this debate. If you read the answer, I do talk in terms of how the verb's state behaves in the situation in a manner that I believe answers the question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Your 'was going' comment is spot on, but I respectfully disagree with the inference you draw from 'solution is to lower the standards'.  IMHO 'to go' in the OP does not equate to 'to lower' in your search phrase, in that the latter is used in a forward-looking statement (i.e., standards have not yet been lowered).  To my mind, 'to go' also belongs in forward-looking statements, which relates to why 'going' would begin the sentence after one has gone.  When we change the word order, 'is going' sounds off but 'was going' works beautifully.

Comment: @Egox I was addressing the answer (hence a comment under the answer) and pointing out the false 'deduction'; I was not addressing the OP directly (which would have required an answer or a comment under the question).

Comment: My second comment above; please read 'as' for 'than'.