# Use of infinitive form of verb with another verb

Tags: infinitives

As a native speaker, this sounds incorrect to me:

> The company does not permit to distribute the modified materials.

But, I can't explain why it is not so to a non-native speaker. To me, it should be:

> The company does not permit distribution of modified materials.

Am I right? What is the grammatical explanation?

Comment: Answered at [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive). (Different verbs allow / need different complement clauses; 'permit' doesn't license a to-infinitve. "The company does not permit us to distribute the modified materials" is a different construction.)

Comment: Some verbs simply require nouns or gerunds.

Comment: It's ungrammatical because an infinitival clause can't satisfy the complement requirements of "permit". When used this way, "permit" usually requires a direct object, or direct object + infinitival clause, cf. _The company does not permit **anyone** to distribute the modified materials_. _The company does not permit (the) distribution of modified materials_, is fine because "(the) distribution of modified materials" is a noun phrase functioning as direct object.

Comment: That's not a good answer, it's not "an exact duplicate", and it doesn't explain anything. It certainly shouldn't be given as The correct answer for anything. The reason why *_The company does not permit to distribute the modified materials_ is ungrammatical is that _permit_ is bitransitive with an infinitive complement, and does not allow an indefinite subject to be deleted with an infinitive, the way it does with a gerund: _They don't permit distributing modified materials to customers_ is fine. Memorizing long lists linked together tenuously simply leads to more confusion.