# What is the tense of the verb, "remark," in this sentence?

Tags: tenses, verb-agreement, participles

Here's the sentence:

> As I walked through the exhibit, I overheard a visitor ***remark***, "You know, that grandfather clock actually runs."

The "subject" of the verb is singular ("visitor"), so if remark is functioning as a verb, it should agree with the subject (whether it's considered past or present tense), so I'm guessing it's serving as a modifier of some sort. Can anyone expound on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a bare infinitive (a.k.a. the simple form of the verb).

- What’s the subject of your main clause?  ***I***
- What’s the primary verb in the main clause?  ***overheard***
- Is the verb transitive or intransitive?  transitive
- What’s the direct object?  ?

Ay, there’s the rub! 
The direct object is the phrase, ***a visitor remark,
“You know, that grandfather clock actually runs.”*** 
Things get a little weird when a phrase with a subject and a verb
acts like a noun. 
We have a list of how to handle those
at [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/329/26083) 
That page doesn’t mention ***overhear***,
but it does state that ***hear*** (and ***see***) are
followed by either the simple form or the gerund (no “to”).

It may make more sense if you consider shorter sentences:

- I heard him ***sing***.
- I heard him ***sing*** the anthem.
- I saw him ***play***.
- I saw him ***throw*** the ball.
- I overheard him ***remark*** blah blah blah.

As indicated above, you can also use gerunds for these verbs:

- I heard him ***singing***.
- I heard him ***singing*** the anthem.
- I saw him ***playing***.
- I saw him ***throwing*** the ball.
- I overheard him ***remarking*** blah blah blah.

Comment: Scott, I cannot thank you enough for your time in responding! I'd been struggling with that quite a bit. You are bona fide grammar god for explaining that in such easy to understand terms. Much appreciated! (Hoping this message will get to you before I delete this shortly to abide by the site suggestions.)

Comment: Thank for the thanks (and for the checkmark), but I’m not even a demigod around here.  Yes, I know grammar somewhat better than the average person (and I mean in the world, not on this site), but mostly I just happened to remember that thread from seven years ago, and I just happened to be the first one to get to your question. Enjoy [SE] (and, yes, follow the rules, or people will get upset).

Comment: Perhaps worth nothing that the use of a gerund puts greater focus on the actual performance of the action, rather than the action as a whole or the subject of that action, as is the case with the infinitive.