# Does the verb “ban” take a gerund or infinitive as its complement?

Tags: grammaticality, gerund-vs-infinitive, predicate-frames

Which one below is correct while using the verb *ban*?

1. Plastic bottle using was banned by government in the country.
2. Government banned to use plastic bottle in the country.
3. Plastic bottle was banned from using  by government in the country.

Comment: All your sentences are ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

*Ban* takes a gerund, but not an infinitive. (There is no explanation for this: it is just an accidental property of that particular word).

The GloWbE corpus has 407 instances of "ban X-ing", but not a single instance of "ban to X".

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence formation is grammatically incorrect. The correct usage would be-

1) Government banned the usage of plastic bottles in the country.

2) Usage of plastic bottles was banned by the government in the country.

3) Same as 1)

4) Plastic bottle was banned from usage by the government in the country.

I suggest reading [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive) post to gain more insight.

Comment: 1) is perfectly grammatical, though less natural than your 1) and 2).

Comment: Your 1 needs an article to be grammatical, and your 4 is quite bizarre to me. The government didn’t ban plastic bottles from using anything. If you want to use that construction, you’d have to say “People were banned by the government from using plastic bottles in the country”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'd say that 4 is OK except that it must be *[**The** plastic bottle was]/[Plastic bottle**s were**] banned from usage…* Examples of this construction from published literature: *[The insecticide diazinon] **was banned from usage** on golf courses in 1990.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=4gypDgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT160&dq=%22was%20banned%20from%20usage%22&pg=PT160#v=onepage&q=%22was%20banned%20from%20usage%22&f=false);

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *All other dialects **were banned from usage*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=vHSKDgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT9&dq=%22were%20banned%20from%20usage%22&pg=PT9#v=onepage&q=%22were%20banned%20from%20usage%22&f=false); *Freshmen were asked to carry a number of items to class with them and ever since the day when books bags **were banned from usage*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Of2NAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA30&dq=%22were%20banned%20from%20usage%22&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q=%22were%20banned%20from%20usage%22&f=false), …

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Of course, alternatively, one could say *[The plastic bottle was]/[Plastic bottles were]  banned from **being used**…*, but then *by the government* becomes ambiguous (did the government ban it, or was the government banned from using it/them?).

Comment: @linguisticturn Yes, “Plastic bottles were banned by the government from being used in the country” works okay for me as well (though it still sounds like the government was telling the bottles not to be used, rather than telling people not to use them). I wouldn’t have expected the other construction to be in actual usage, but apparently it is – it’s still strange to me, but clearly not to everyone.