# "I like watching" vs "I like to watch" What's the difference?

Tags: meaning, gerund-vs-infinitive

Which of the two possibilities would native speakers more likely say when they watch a football (soccer or American) match from the comfort of their home?

> What sport do you watch most on television?
>
> 1. I like watching football
> 2. I like to watch football

And if the speaker went to a stadium to watch football matches, which sentence would they be more likely to say? Do native speakers (especially British and American) say they *watch* football in a stadium?

**Is there a difference in meaning** or *usage* if the speaker is thinking of their physical presence at the sporting event?

> What sport do you watch most?
>
> 3. I like watching football [in a stadium]
> 4. I like to watch football [in a stadium]

- If someone enjoyed all the rituals leading to the match; the travelling to the stadium, the football chants, the fast food, the camaraderie with fellow supporters, everything that is part of a live sporting event, which sentence might they say: 3 or 4?
- Without prompting, would “like (to) + watch(ing)” be a common response or would a different verb be used with “like” for instance “go”?
- Would it be in the gerund or the infinitive form? Is there a syntactic or semantic explanation for this preference?

---

### EDIT

This question is *not* a duplicate of  [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive) which simply asks

> “Which particular verbs are followed by ing and to? Can you please provide a list for that?”

**This post is not asking for any list**, it is not asking which verbs take the infinitive or the gerund. The answers on the older question handle that matter well enough. Instead, my question is one that frequently comes up among learners and ESOL teachers, it is specific and necessitates a deeper analysis and more thoughtful approach than saying there is no difference in meaning between the two forms. Native speakers are aware of this difference but find it difficult to verbalise, and ESOL and EFL teachers often struggle to explain *why* the verb “like“ can be followed by the infinitive or the gerund.

Not all verbs are this problematic, the verb *remember* can also be followed by either the infinitive or the gerund, e.g. *“to remember **to do** something”* and *“remember **doing** something”* But the two constructions have two distinct meanings, and they are not interchangeable.

The following expresses the memory of performing that activity e.g.

> “*He **remembers swimming** in the lake as a child*”

The speaker recalls the experience, and the process it entailed: getting undressed, getting into a pair of swimming trunks, running to the shore, the initial impact of the cold water on his warm body, and so on. However, in

> “*We must **remember to swim** where there is a lifeguard*”

The speaker is not thinking of the past, there is no fond recollection of that experience, the person is not concerned with the actual process of walking along the beach, spotting whether there is a blue or red flag flying, and seeing if a lifeguard is present etc.  Instead, the speaker is thinking of the event itself, and reminding the listener not to ignore this important piece of information. The same cannot be said for

*I **like to watch** football on television*
*I **like watching** football on television*

What is the difference in meaning (and usage) between the two forms? I feel there must be, but I am having difficulty in pinpointing it. When would someone instinctively say one form over the other?

To sum up, I am specifically asking about the difference in *meaning* and *usage* between “I like to watch” and “I like watching”, the older question simply does not address this issue.

Comment: It's been a long time since I actually spent much time watching either live football (soccer), or football on TV, so I won't post an 'answer'. "I go to United / to watch United most weeks" // "I often watch football on TV" would be my usual responses if asked 50 years ago. Possibly "I like ..." sounded more unmacho. I'm not sure about distribution of -ing form vs infinitive. The to-infinitive form sounds more punchy, so perhaps I'd favour that back in the day.

Comment: You ask which of **two** possibilities is the ***most*** likely. You could improve the clarity of the question by asking which of the **two** is ***more*** likely.  This seems better than increasing the choices beyond two here so that *most* can rightly apply.

Comment: Hmm. I think this ***is*** a duplicate of [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/). The top answer there says ***Sometimes the meaning changes according to the verb [form] used*** - giving as examples *He won't remember **giving** the homework to Mr. Young / He won’t remember **to give** the homework to Mr. Young*. The potential semantic distinction is also addressed on ELL: [Why is “He knows to swim” incorrect?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31852/) (which it *isn't* necessarily, obviously! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not asking when a gerund or an infinitive should be used, I'm asking what is the difference in meaning, be it subtle or barely perceived or unconscious. This is a question that comes up very frequently among learners and ESOL teachers. *To remember **to do** something* and *remembering* **doing** something* have two different meanings. I can explain that. But what about *I **like to** watch* and *I **like** watch**ing***? Where's the answer to that?

Comment: There's something noteworthy about whether the verb *watch* can **ever** be used for eyewitness viewing of such live events as sporting matches, theatrical productions, circus acts, or parades--or whether some other verb **must** be used to distinguish that from following "televised" video feeds via some screen. Choice of nonfinite verb clause (gerund vs infinitive) is likely tangential and distracting from that crucial aspect. If instead a **finite** verb like past tense *watched* or nonpast tense *watches* were used, all contagion risk from the putative duplicate could be safely banished.

Comment: Sorry - was afk. The answer to the *specific* distinction between, say, *He knows **lying*** (he's good at lying or recognising lies) and *He knows **to lie*** (he knows he ***must*** lie) is covered by one or both of those links. You could argue for a minuscule nuance of difference between ***like to [verb]*** and ***like [verbing]*** in some contexts (and with *some* verbs), but often that's just pointless pontificating about meanings that don't really exist if they're not normally recognised by native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the ELL link is irrelevant here. This is EL&U and this post is closed  for being a dupe of an EL&U one. I see my arguments have not swayed you one inch. I'll wait patiently for the 5th reopen vote.

Comment: I think the *usage* difference with **like + watch** is simply that the continuous / gerund form, which was practically non-existent a couple of centuries ago has now become the idiomatically preferred choice. I don't know if it applies with other verbs, but for this *specific* pair, NGrams suggests this shift occurred first in BrE (the gerund had achieved parity by WW1, and become the clear leader after WW2). I defy anyone to justify any *semantic* distinction for normal contexts though.

Comment: [...NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28like+to+watch%29%2B%28likes+to+watch%29%2B%28liked+to+watch%29%2C%28like+watching%29%2B%28likes+watching%29%2B%28liked+watching%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28like%20to%20watch%29%20%2B%20%28likes%20to%20watch%29%20%2B%20%28liked%20to%20watch%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28like%20watching%29%20%2B%20%28likes%20watching%29%20%2B%20%28liked%20watching%29%3B%2Cc0) illustrating point made in previous comment. Switch to BrE corpus to see the difference.

Comment: ...in which context I'd also point out that *[I'm] Sorry **for interrupting** [you]* has in recent decades started to make some headway against *[I'm] Sorry **to interrupt** [you]*. But it's still practically always *I **would** like **to watch** TV* rather than *I **would** like **watching** TV* - though one could probably make a case for certain contexts having more "justification" for the newly-emerging form there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers looks like a good answer to me.

Answer (score 3):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/common-verbs/hate-like-love-and-prefer), on verbs like ***hate, like, love and prefer***, makes the following remarks:

> We can use hate, like, love and prefer with an -ing form or with a to-infinitive:
>
> In American English, the forms with to-infinitive are much more common than the -ing form.
>
> ***There is a very small difference in meaning between the two forms***.

Note that:

> ***The -ing form emphasises the action or experience***,
>
> - *I like making jam.
>   He likes telling jokes.
>   They don’t like sitting for too long.*

while

> ***The to-infinitive gives more emphasis to the results of the action or event***,
>
> - *I like to make jam every year*.

also

> We often use the -ing form to suggest enjoyment (or lack of it), and the to-infinitive form to express habits or preferences.

Answer (score 2):

*Which form would native speakers most likely say when they watch football (soccer or American) matches from the comfort of their home?*

In AmE, IMHO, your samples 1 and 2 are appropriate.

*Is there a difference in meaning or usage if the speaker is thinking of their physical presence at the sporting event?*

In lieu of your samples, I suggest:

> I like going to football games.

I am not sure of semantic reasonings. In summary, **"I like going to a football game"** or **"I like to go to a football game"** (or match)? are   one in the same.  I wouldn't normally say **"watch football in a stadium."**

> *Hey, are you watching Monday-nite football tonight?  I sure am!  I am actually going to the game.*

Comment: As an American English speaker, would you say that you watch football in a stadium?

Comment: Why would you suggest "going" and can you tell me what is the difference between  "I like going to a football game" and "I like to go to  a football game" (or match)? Thanks!

Comment: No. I would say I am going/ went to the game.  To watch is imputed.

Comment: "I like going to a football game" or "I like to go to a football game" (or match)? // semantically one in the same.

Comment: aye aye ... shall so edit.