# Which is correct: "To believe this is committing a fallacy" or "To believe this is to commit a fallacy"?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct: "To believe this is committing a fallacy" or "To believe this is to commit a fallacy"?

Context: "When a conditional expression and its consequent are both true, one cannot automatically infer its antecedent. To believe the contrary is  committing/to commit a fallacy known as affirming the consequent".

Edit: I changed "incurring/to incur" to "committing/to commit", but I'm still hearing proposals...

Comment: Both constructions seem highly improbable, could you give us context to work with?

Comment: If you were to remove the word "in" either construction seems sound to me, but wait for someone to give a propper answer though.

Comment: It probably should be *to **commit** a fallacy*. Google has 10 times as many hits for *commit a fallacy* as for *incur a fallacy* (and *incur in a fallacy* is clearly wrong).

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks, Peter, so, "to "commit", not "committing", right?

Comment: Both "to commit" and "committing" are grammatical, but I like "to commit" much better because it is parallel with "to believe".

Comment: @PeterShor Oh, so both "incurring" and "to incur" must be grammatical too, then, although I see that it is not a word commonly used for fallacies...

Comment: This question frequently gets asked on the site. Does this supply an answer? [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive)

Comment: @WS2 Neither "to be" nor "believe" feature in those lists...

Comment: You will have noted that it does say: *Most verbs are followed by infinitives. If the verb is not found in the list below, it is probably followed by an infinitive.*.And as does @PeterShor I find the infinitive sounds better here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Strunk & White's *The Elements of Style*:

> 19. Express coordinate ideas in similar form.
>       This principle, that of parallel construction, requires that expressions similar in content and function be outwardly similar. The likeness of form enables the reader to recognize more readily the likeness of content and function.

Using this principle, "To believe...to commit..." would be the preferred construction.